# resize image with jquery function

Tags: jquery, html, image, css

I need to resize the width and height of three images. I want to do it with jQuery.

I applied some CSS to do that but it fails because the image inside the class `col-md-6` moves to the right. I want this image to be fixed instead of  moved to the right.

Here is my code:

```css
#img1:hover {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}

#img2:hover {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}

#img3:hover {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}

.col-centered {
    float: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6" id="mision">
        <img src="imagenes/MISION.png" id="img1" class="resize">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6" id="vision">
        <img src="imagenes/VISION.png" id="img2" class="resize">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-centered" id="servicios">
        <img src="imagenes/SERVICIOS.png" id="img3" class="resize">
    </div>
</div
```

Comment: It's really unclear what you want. You don't even have defined a size for your images, only for their hover states, but you write nothing about hovering...

Answer (score 0):

Haven't used bootstrap before, but a quick googleling suggests

```
.table-img {
  width: 100px;
}

.table-img:hover {
  width: 200px;
}
```

and

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 text-center" id="mision">
    <img src="imagenes/MISION.png" class="resize">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 text-center" id="vision">
    <img src="imagenes/VISION.png" class="resize">
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6 text-center col-centered" id="servicios">
    <img src="imagenes/SERVICIOS.png" class="resize">
  </div>
</div>
```

text-center is for centering your image, and the adjusted css should work for hovering and increasing size of the images.

Please let me know if didn't understand your question correctly.